# Populate a picker from code - React native

Tags: react-native

Using the component https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker, I am trying to create a dropdown list that uses values from an API.
I found the article on https://alexb72.medium.com/how-to-populate-react-native-picker-dynamically-with-values-from-an-api-dbe122e85a5a, which aims to do the same.
However, it throws errors right at the start, just by creating App.js:

```
ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). 
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
    This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). 
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
    This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

I am running in Android Emulator.
Does anyone have a working project?

Comment: This can sometimes happen when adding new packages to the node modules folder. Try cleaning the project and running it again. 

If that does not work, trying importing React like this: import * as React from 'react';

Comment: Also, share some code of your imports and the logic around the picker.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is that the article uses an old version of react native.
Instead of this: "class App extends React.Component {", we are now using "const App = () => {".
Other parts of the code throw error too because of the outdated nomenclature.

I got the list to work, however, it can only be loaded by pressing a button. In the old versions of react native, there was a function called componentDidMount, but it cannot be used now, and setting the state in the constructor will render the page in an infinite loop. Do you know what the new lifecycle methods are? I haven't found any documentation of them.

Here is my code:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';

const App = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState();

    async function req() {
        let userValues = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response => response.json());

        setUsers(userValues.map((myValue,myIndex) => {
            console.log('User: ' + myValue.name + "  - " + myIndex);

            return(
                <Picker.Item label={myValue.name + ' - ' + myValue.username} value={myIndex} key={myIndex}/>
            )
        }))
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Button
                color='green'
                title="Load users"
                onPress={() =>
                    req()
                }
            />
            <Picker
                mode="dialog"
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                { 
                }}>
                {users}
            </Picker>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

export default App;
```